# Entity Framework - Primary Key Constraint Violation when key is not in database already

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework to add items to a context then save the context. I am having an odd issue where after my application has ran a certain length of time, I start getting Primary Key Constraint violations for keys that I am sure are not in the database when I save the changes to the context. Once this happens, it starts to happen on every save of the context. When I restart the application this error goes away.

There isn't much code to show past adding the object to the context and saving the context's changes. The IDs are GUIDs that are created outside of the creation of the object and then applied to the object, not an auto-increment ID.

Comment: Have you debugged your code to ensure that the ID's you are attempting to save are unique and not in the database?

Comment: I have access to the logs which state the ID and the database that is being saved to. I don't have access to debug while this is happening.

Comment: Additionally, once this happens once, it happens for every save attempt following it.

Comment: You're not reusing the same DbContext are you?

Comment: Yep, it looks like it is. I'm assuming that's bad by the fact you're asking.

Comment: Yes, a new context should generally be created for each _action/transaction_ you want to perform on the database. DbContext tracks entities returned from the database (so it can detect updates etc), and the longer you are using it, the more memory it requires

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement it.